# Koin Test checkModules()

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

I am writing a test to validate the Koin dependency graph setup. But when I run the test, I get an error, what am I doing wrong? The test fails, but the application starts and runs fine

Error:

```
org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException: Could not create instance for [Single:'com.example.vkmessenger.local.UserDao']
```

Test:

```
class MyTest : KoinTest {

    @Test
    fun checkModulesTest() {

    val mockApplication = module(override = true) {
            single { mock(Application::class.java) }
            single { mock(Context::class.java) }
        }

        koinApplication {
            modules(listOf(mockApplication, viewModelModule, appModule, serviceModule))
        }.checkModules()
    }
```

appModule

```
val appModule = module {

    single { provideDispatcher() }
    single { provideUserDao(provideDatabase(androidContext())) }
    single { provideFriendsDao(provideDatabase(androidContext())) }
    single { provideVkApi() }

    single<VkNetworkDataSource> { VkRetrofitDataSource(get(), get()) }
    single<VkLocalDataSource> { VkRoomDataSource(get(), get(), get()) }
    single<VkRepository> { VkDefaultRepository(get(), get(), get()) }
}
```

ViewModelModule:

```
val viewModelModule = module {
    viewModel { AuthorizationViewModel(get()) }
    viewModel { FriendsViewModel(get()) }
    viewModel { FriendsOnlineViewModel(get()) }
}
```

ServiceModule:

```
val serviceModule = module {
    single { StatusTrackingServiceInteractor(get()) }
}
```